React Native build a central database file
I'm new to react native and I want to create a file who manage all the database stuff, like save, get, delete and so on.
I want to create a database file exporting a single object with CRUD functions (save, get, delete, etc..) for component reuse.
My APP has a folder structure with recipes in it. I need the folder structure in different components. So i don't want to load the folder structure in every component (and other functions), i wan't to have it load one time in the database file and use it in different components.
I want it later for different users, so i need the data in a database, or in my case database likable because I want to use firestore.
But I'm not sure how I can manage to call the functions in other components. I want it like that:
databasefile.jsx

export database{

getListOfSomething(){
   return list;
}

deleteItem(itemNumber){
   delete stuff;
   return whatEver;
}
}

otherFile.jsx
import database from databasefile;

list = database.getListOfSomething();

etc...

is something like that possible?
Thank you in advance
i tried it with export default function and declare the functions inside but it doesn't work, like this:
import { useState } from "react";

export default function DataBase() {
    const data = [
        {
            recipeId: '156',
            name: 'recipe1',
            isFavorit: true
        },
        {
            recipeId: '356',
            name: 'recipe2',
            isFavorit: true
        },
        {
            recipeId: '897',
            name: 'recipe3',
            isFavorit: false
        },
    ]

    const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState(data);

    function getFolderList(){
        return recipes;
    }

}

and Import it like that:
import DataBase from "../dataBase";  

const folder = DataBase.getFolderList();

and i saw the solution with export, but it didn't match what i want...
I don't want to export every function.

You can create a single object to manage all your database functions and reuse it across components like this:
database.js
let data = [
    { recipeId: '156', name: 'recipe1', isFavorit: true },
    { recipeId: '356', name: 'recipe2', isFavorit: true },
    { recipeId: '897', name: 'recipe3', isFavorit: false },
];

const database = {
    getFolderList() {
        return data;
    },
    saveRecipe(recipe) {
        data.push(recipe);
        return recipe;
    },
    deleteRecipe(recipeId) {
        data = data.filter(recipe => recipe.recipeId !== recipeId);
    },
};

export default database;

and you can call the functions like this:
import database from './database';

const recipes = database.getFolderList();
console.log(recipes);

database.saveRecipe({ recipeId: '123', name: 'recipe4', isFavorit: false });
console.log(database.getFolderList());

database.deleteRecipe('123');
console.log(database.getFolderList());

This way, all CRUD operations are centralized in a single object.
For better state management in larger applications, I recommend using tools like useReducer or a state management library like Redux
